# What verb and payload to set an API resource to 301 Moved?

Tags: api, rest, redirect

Say I have two objects in a RESTful API:

```
 /resource/blue
 /resource/red
```

Now I want to combine the two of them and point them to a new object

```
/resource/orange
```

When I go to /resource/blue or red I want to receive a response like

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 21:57:47 GMT
Location: /resource/orange
```

So far so good... we can set that pragmatically in Spring based on data in Mongo. But what would be the best RESTful request to make to change my blue resource into a 301 redirect to my new orange resource?  Should it be...

```
PUT /resource/blue
{"movedto" : "/resource/orange"}
```

Or

```
DELETE /resource/blue
{"movedto" : "/resource/orange"}
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really looks like a `PUT`, because you're updating the resource (its location), and moving it twice should have no effect (you get the `301`/`303`), because it's already there.

If you used a `DELETE` twice on the same resource, the call would try to delete a resource that's no longer there (it's been moved), so it should actually return a `404`.

Also, [by definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) the `DELETE` verb:

> SHOULD NOT indicate success unless, at the time the response is given,
>   it intends to delete the resource or move it to an inaccessible
>   location.

And the location where you're moving the resource is not going to be inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use HTTP 303 (see other) instead of HTTP 301 (moved)

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: http://your.domain/resource/orange
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay... But the question still stands... What would the correct RESTful call be to set it to 303?

Comment: @MichaelBissell all verbs, OPTIONS GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE TRACE CONNECT PATCH